# is cors middleware the same as sending headers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors

For a node project, I am using cors. Two options are available, one is [cors middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors), the other is sending headers like:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", CLIENT_ORIGIN);
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    return res.sendStatus(204);
  }
  next();
});
```

Is there a difference in using either? Does one use another? Do I need both?

Answer (score 2):

I would use the npm cors package that you have listed for what you are aiming to achieve.  You do not need to manually set headers when you are using this cors library, unless you are wanting to set extra headers that the cors package does not set.

I have used this package specifically for the whitelist feature, where you can include a list of domains that you want to allow to make requests to your API (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuring-cors-w-dynamic-origin).

Answer (score 1):

CORS middleware is a middleware for [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/) framework, you don't need to use both. 
If you are using Express.js then I suggest you to use [expressjs/cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) middleware better than sending headers like you mentionned in your question.